# How can you lock the volume control programmatically

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I want to intercept volume control changes and ignore them. Ideally this functionality could be backgrounded so my app would not have to be open and would work on the lockscreen as well. It also needs to work on an API greater than 21.

Answer (score 0):

Take reference from this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/volume-and-earphones

To ensure that volume controls adjust the correct stream, you should call `setVolumeControlStream()` passing in the stream type matching your attributes that you can retrieve from `AudioAttributes.getVolumeControlStream.`

Make this call in your app’s lifecycle, typically from the `onResume()` method of the activity or fragment that controls your media. This connects the volume controls to `STREAM_MUSIC` whenever the target activity or fragment is visible.

Comment: please check the https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/volume-and-earphones